# How do I dynamically create a flutter app based on arguments supplied?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to create a form that asks user the name of the application, icon, permissions needs to be added, etc and generate APK/IPA based on the given parameters.
Can anyone help me with the same?

I tried passing parameters in flutter app using CLI, but I am not sure how to modify the package name, icon and dynamically ask permissions in the app.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is this a command-line application? Desktop application?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Soliev I want to create a webform and generate APK/IPA based on the inputs given by user.